# How to get focus-out event for select field in EmberJS?

Tags: ember.js

I want to perform some action when the user has lost focus from the input fields.

The `focus-out` property works well for the input fields but has no effect on the select input.

```
{{view "select" class="form-control"
   content=options
   optionValuePath="content.id"
   optionLabelPath="content.value"
   selection= value
   focus-out=submitAction}}
```

How can I get the focus out event for select inputs?

Comment: What version of Ember are you using? Views, and `select`, were removed in 2.0.

Comment: There are a couple alternatives that I would suggest, like [x-select](https://github.com/thefrontside/emberx-select) and [power-select](http://www.ember-power-select.com/).